# unable to drop ERROR: unknown compresstype "quicklz" unable to drop

Tags: postgresql-9.2, greenplum

We have some tables defined with compression type as 'quicklz' in our Open-source greenplum database version 6.24.6. Which we want to drop.

While dropping such objects it throws below error:

ERROR: unknown compresstype "quicklz"

Any way to drop those objects in Greenplum?